# Multi Thread Programming

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a task. I have some random number, wich contains value of this number, and delay.

Delay means, that after this delay (in seconds) this number gonna be updated (value and delay).

And all I need to do is next: for example I have 5 numbers. All of them are on the same form. So when programm start, it must take first number, get its delay, do smth like Thread.Sleep(delay) for this number, update it, then get second number, get delay and so on. When it reach the last one, it must get first number again, then second and so on. Like loop.

I'm new in threads. So could someone explain me how should it work?

So I have main form, then I have 5 UserControls on it (I keep them in List<>). Each control have UpdateNumber() method, which update value and delay of current number. What should I do on main form? Do I need create Thread[] array? Then put each UserControl in there? Then start all of them and monitor them somehow?

I think it smth about Thread.Join. But for me, as for newbie it's pretty complicated.

P.S. and than I need to next task. It's the same, but all this numbers works separetly. For example first numbers has 5 second delay in the begining. When it reachs 5 second delay, it's update itself. Second number and all others do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid creating threads and using `Thread.Sleep()`. Each thread is an expensive resource to create and since it will be asleep the majority of the time, it will be wasted the majority of the time. Also, when it executes it may cause context switching since the CPU's may be saturated.

Instead, I would consider using a `System.Threading.Timer`. For instance, you initially set the `Timer` to operate on the first value. After this operation is complete you use your 'delay' to set the `Timer` to execute the code that will read the next value using `Timer.Change()` and so on. I'm not sure I understand your requirements completely but it sounds like you should be able to satisfy most of them using a `Timer`. The `Timer` will use the `ThreadPool` which will avoid unnecessary thread creation and context switching.

To learn more about multi-threading I highly recommend Jeffrey Richter's book CLR via C# (part V). Multi-threading is very powerful but it is incredibly easy to get totally wrong. IMHO anyone who wants to write multi-threaded code should at least read a good text such as this before starting.

Comment: The OP mentions a 'main form' so I tink a Windows.Forms.Timer would be better. Avoids Invoke issues with the GUI.

Comment: @Henk: noted, although I would still rather use a `System.Threading.Timer` and only use the GUI thread for those operations which need it, i.e. reading and writing to controls. The question doesn't reveal the extent of the non-GUI related processing which take place (e.g. using the numeric value for some kind of business logic) but I think it's better to perform this on a non-GUI thread and isolate only GUI-related operations to be invoked on the GUI thread explicitly. I concede that this involves more code but it will help to keep the GUI responsive as the application grows.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on what I have read I do not see any compelling reason to use threads at all. I mean you are just generating different random numbers based on some time interval so it cannot possibly be that CPU intensive. Just use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in each `UserControl`. When the `Tick` event handler is executed then just generate next number.

If you are asking if it is a good idea to run each `UserControl` in a different thread then the answer is most definitely no. All UI elements including `Form`'s and `Control`'s must run in the specially designated UI thread. This is mandatory. It will not work right correctly (or at all) on a free thread.

Regarding calling `Thread.Join`; do not attempt this, at least on a UI thread anyway. Calling `Join` on a UI thread will block the windows message dispatching mechanisms. It will appear as if the whole UI hung up.